# NSLayoutConstraint re-activated on layout change?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a layout constraint in one of my views in the storyboard which I deactivate (`.isActive = false`) to add an additional view. Works so far without problems. If I rotate to landscape the constraint however is active again and causes a small conflict. Do someone know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: enable and disable constraint  in `viewDidLayoutSubview` method , when you rotate layout is realoded again ,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
_yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```